# Match a Pipe delimited string having column names of different table, once column name match update it as 'GOOD'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Ex. String(column of Table T with name Planets) =' Sun|Earth|Mars';
Table(T) column headers are Planet, Sun, Venus, Mars.

As Mars is common in both, then the value of Mars should be updated as Y in table T.

Table T there are such 50+ columns with which I have to extract and match then update as Y

```
| pluto |   Sun   |   Earth   |  Mars   |  Planets               |
|-------|---------|-----------|---------|  --------------------- |
|       |   Y     |    Y      |   Y     | Sun|Earth|Mars         |
|  Y    |         |    Y      |         |   Pluto|Earth          |
|       |         |           |         |    (Blank)             |
```

If the Planet column data is matching with other columns as sun or earth then update those columns as Y.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help thequestion.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you may need:

```
update T
set Pluto   = case when planets like '%Pluto%' then 'Y' end,
    Sun     = case when planets like '%Sun%'   then 'Y' end,
    Earth   = case when planets like '%Earth%' then 'Y' end,   
    Mars    = case when planets like '%Mars%'  then 'Y' end
```

An example:

```
SQL> create table T (
  2      Pluto   varchar2(1),
  3      Sun     varchar2(1),
  4      Earth   varchar2(1),
  5      Mars    varchar2(1),
  6      Planets varchar2(100)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into T (Pluto, Sun, Earth, Mars, Planets) values (null, null, null, null, 'Sun|Earth|Mars');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into T (Pluto, Sun, Earth, Mars, Planets) values (null, null, null, null, 'Pluto|Earth');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into T (Pluto, Sun, Earth, Mars, Planets) values (null, null, null, null, null);

1 row created.

SQL> update T
  2  set pluto   = case when planets like '%Pluto%' then 'Y' end,
  3      Sun     = case when planets like '%Sun%'   then 'Y' end,
  4      Earth   = case when planets like '%Earth%' then 'Y' end,
  5      Mars    = case when planets like '%Mars%'  then 'Y' end;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from T;

PLUTO      SUN        EARTH      MARS       PLANETS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
           Y          Y          Y          Sun|Earth|Mars
Y                     Y                     Pluto|Earth


3 rows selected.
```

Comment: But the Planet is a pipe-delimited string

Comment: With your sample data , this updates the columns exactly the way you posted. If this is not what you need, please post a different sample data and try to better explain the logics behind

Comment: your answer is really commendable, but I am doing for excel generation. So the challenge is to break the delimited column and the values present in the delimited column should match with the column having the same name.

Comment: Please, post an example that shows what you need to do. If you need to update a table, show the data before and after the update; if you need a select, post the table content and the needed result. As is, it's hard to understand what you need

Comment: I used the same thing but it is updating pluto every time, don't know why